# How do I insert the data array to 8 tables at once?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have a variable with the contents of the array is as below

```
$dataRoles = [
  0 => [
   'data1',
   'data2',
   'data3'
 ],

  1 => [
  'data4',
  'data5'
 ]
]
```

and I have 2 tables table role_0, and role_1.

How to insert a data array 0 => '....' to the table role_0 and array 1 => '....' to the table role_1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to make insert into 2 different tables. It's only possible to insert into 1 table but many records using bulk insert e.g:

```
insert into table (fld1, fld2) values ("val1", "val2"), ("val3", "val4"), ...
```